# How to disable App Service authentication for a path?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I enabled [identity federation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) [V2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-api-version#update-the-configuration-version) for an App Service that hosts a single page app. This works fine but now I need to disable it again for routes that start with `/.well-known/` because that's where I store files that don't require authentication, e.g. [apple-app-site-associations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains).

In previous versions, I was able to upload an `authorization.json` file to my App Service to  disable authentication for this path, but this no longer works?

```json
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "path_prefix": "/",
      "policies": {
        "unauthenticated_action": "RedirectToLoginPage"
      }
    },
    {
      "path_prefix": "/.well-known/",
      "policies": {
        "unauthenticated_action": "AllowAnonymous"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: Auth settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still unsure why the old way of configuring path exclusions stopped working, but I figured out how to do it with V2 configuration.

First migrate to file-based configuration as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-file-based#enabling-file-based-configuration

In short, copy all config from `Microsoft.Web/sites/<siteName>/config/authsettingsV2` to a file in your wwwroot folder, e.g. `wwwroot/auth.json`. This file will be accessible over HTTP so remove secrets from configuration as documented. Set `platform.configFilePath` to `auth.json` and restart the app service.

Once you've confirmed that everything still works with file-based configuration, you can add path exclusions to the configuration file.

```json
{
  "platform": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "globalValidation": {
    ...
    "excludedPaths": [
      "/.well-known/apple-app-site-association",
      "/.well-known/assetlinks.json"
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

Restart the app service one more time for changes to take effect.

Comment: Thank you! I did not need to switch to a file-based configuration to make it work. I used `excludePaths` in my bicep file.

Comment: Is this only for static files? I was trying to exclude my API route but it's not working for me. Also, is it required to set the platformRuntime setting?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio it should work for any path, static or otherwise, there is no indication in the docs that it matters. I don't know what you mean by platformRuntime, there is no key with that name.

Comment: @StevenLiekens when calling the REST api endpoint, the response payload contains such setting with ~1 value

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying this 12/2022, it seems that "configFilePath" is not working for quite some time ([evidence](https://codesti.com/issue/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/81449))

If you change directly on Azure Resource Explorer, it works.